# JQuery cleaning up eventhandlers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm an actionscript developer getting into jquery/javascript development. I have a question regarding event handlers and binding/unbinding.

Say for instance that I have for an div with a img element with an onerror event handler in it. If i replace that that div with a new one do i need to remove the eventhandler bound to the img element. Since the img no longer will be in the document will browsers be smart enough to remove it or will I have a caused memory leak?

Comming from actionscript i usually try to constantly remove old eventhandlers. So do i need to do this when writing javascript for web browsers?

The event handlers are added with `$('imgElement').error(errorFunction);`

Comment: How are the event handlers added?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're binding the events with jQuery just call [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) on the old element before replacing it, or [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) if you just want to clear it, both of these clean up event handlers for the element and it's children, or in the case of [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/), just the children.

If you just replace it, e.g. `.html(content)` you *will* leak memory, as any handlers or data for those elements will be left on the `$.cache` object.

Comment: Are you sure? Looking at the jQuery source code, manipulation.js line 203:"// Remove element nodes and prevent memory leaks"

Comment: @phil- If you look at the code before it, you'll see there are several conditions in place that determine if that code executes :)  SO Chat had the same memory leaking issue in the first preview, this was the cause.

Answer (score 0):

try using [firequery](http://firequery.binaryage.com/), its a firefox plugin that shows all active event listeners and jquery.data()

I'm also curious as to whether it's best practice to unbind() events...